# Convert floating-point number to words

Tags: ruby, numbers, number-formatting, output-formatting

How do I get the word-equivalent of a floating-point number? E.g.

- 10.24 → ten point twenty-four
- 5.113 → five point hundred and thirteen

Comment: Do you mean, you have a number and you want to get the word representation of that number?

Comment: exactly! i want to get the word of float numbers

Comment: I recommend you use the linguistics gem, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There's a gem called [numbers_and_words](https://github.com/kslazarev/numbers_and_words) for that! I've used it in several projects without any problems so far.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [linguistics](https://github.com/ged/linguistics) gem:

```
require 'linguistics'
Linguistics.use( :en )

p 10.24.en.numwords #=> "ten point two four"
p 5.113.en.numwords #=> "five point one one three"
```

or try to use this hack as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4117085/1085998) to get more precision:

```
require "linguistics"
Linguistics::use(:en)

class Float
  def my_numwords
    self.to_s.split('.').collect { |n| n.en.numwords }.join(' point ')
  end
end

p 10.24.my_numwords #=> "ten point two four"
p 5.113.my_numwords #=> ""five point one hundred and thirteen"
```